# Ubuntu 19.04 + rethinkdb - don't work together?

Tags: 19.04

It seems that we can't install [rethinkdb](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/) on ubuntu 19.04.

I tried this:

```
source /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list
wget -qO- https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rethinkdb
```

But I get **no candidate issue**.

I tried to build from the source, but I get the following error in the end:

$ sudo make install

```
[1/233] CC build/release/obj/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/s2.o
In file included from src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/s2.cc:197:
./src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/util/math/exactfloat/exactfloat.h:502:10: error: field ‘bn_’ has incomplete type ‘BIGNUM’ {aka ‘bignum_st’}
   BIGNUM bn_;
          ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:19,
                 from ./src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/util/math/exactfloat/exactfloat.h:103,
                 from src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/s2.cc:197:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:80:16: note: forward declaration of ‘BIGNUM’ {aka ‘struct bignum_st’}
 typedef struct bignum_st BIGNUM;
                ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/s2.cc:197:
./src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/util/math/exactfloat/exactfloat.h: In constructor ‘geo::ExactFloat::ExactFloat()’:
./src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/util/math/exactfloat/exactfloat.h:562:3: error: ‘BN_init’ was not declared in this scope
   BN_init(&bn_);
   ^~~~~~~
./src/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/util/math/exactfloat/exactfloat.h:562:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘BN_print’
   BN_init(&bn_);
   ^~~~~~~
   BN_print
make[1]: *** [src/build.mk:392: build/release/obj/rdb_protocol/geo/s2/s2.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:53: make] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt does not support all releases; it's not a Ubuntu supported repository (3rd party) so it's up to you to verify it supports your release.

Comment: @guiverc i dont get it. what do u mean `up to you to verify it supports your release.`? how do i verify it?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  talks about what repositories are available, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors provides a list of authorized mirrors (some of which are not-up-to-date and thus can create issues) - you've added a non-Ubuntu/non-Canonical source (ie. 3rd party) thus is not vetted by Ubuntu/Canonical and all security-risks are on you; you added it.  As for that example, I copy that link from your error messages, and pasted it into a browser to look for myself... it didn't support artful, cosmic, or any standard release since zesty (17.04) ...

Comment: It's pretty easy to see it's non-Ubuntu/Canonical; there is no ubuntu.com in the name, nor authorized mirror (isn't in the archive list I provided), but even if you didn't check that - just pasted link into a browser; it has support for wheezy, jessie, stretch.. (Ubuntu doesn't use toy-story characters as release names!) etc...  easy security checks that should be done before adding any 3rd party source of packages to a system you use/maintain/trust..

Comment: @guiverc i think it does not support disco dist. so anything can be done?

Comment: I don't know the packages, the fact that it mixes debian/ubuntu there would make me worry about their versioning (Ubuntu & Debian packages versions rarely match; not an issue until release-upgrade time! and disco is 2/3rd+ thru it's life-cycle) ... You could add something it does have to your system; but it could be a time-bomb which will hit release-upgrade time....  ie. lots of checking is required before you should do it, and as suggested I don't know the packages so have no idea how risky it will be (it could be minimal/not-a-concern - why you need to check).

Comment: @guiverc probably i should wait until the new release...

Comment: fyi: 19.10 was released last thursday; though 19.04->19.10 upgrade taps weren't enabled last night, but should be in next ~42-66 hours.

Comment: I am trying to upgrade to 19.10 now to see if i get any luck